# Union property does not exist on union type

Tags: typescript

I've following issue in TypeScript:

```
type Foo = {
  a: number
}

type Bar = {
  b: number
}

type Props = {
  object?: Foo | Bar | null;
  keys?: (keyof Foo)[] | (keyof Bar)[];
}

function myFunction({ object, keys = ['a'] }: Props) {
  const values = keys.map(key => object && object[key]);
  // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"a" | "b"' can't be used to index type 'Foo | Bar'.
  // Property 'b' does not exist on type 'Foo | Bar'.
}
```

How would you write types for such a scenario, where then inputs can either be of type Foo or of type Bar?

I'm trying to build an abstraction that can take in two objects and the keys to select from those objects. The objects passed in can be either of type A or of type C. They can have infinite keys, but the caller has to pass in the keys that match the object passed.

Comment: What exactly is the point of `Props` over just passing `Foo` or `Bar` (or `null`)? Are you going to be passing in a *subset* of the keys for `keys?` or is it going to be all keys always? Would is `{ object: { a: 42 }, keys: []}` something that makes sense as input? If you are always going to expect all keys, then `Props` seems superfluous as you can have `props: Foo | Bar | null` and then grab the keys/values/entries of the passed in object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Props` is bad as it is, you are not discriminating the props of `Foo` and `Bar`.

You can use a generic

```js
type Props<T> = {
  object?: T | null;
  keys?: (keyof T)[];
};

function myFunction<T extends Foo | Bar>({ object, keys = ['a'] as (keyof T)[] }: Props<T>) {
  const values = keys.map(key => object && object[key]);
}
```

Now I left the `null` and the optional inputs but if you intend to return something from this function, I strongly suggest you tighten your API, otherwise users will have to do all sorts of checks

Comment: Note that extending `Foo | Bar` is not required for this pattern to work

Comment: This does not seem to work with a default input: `{ object, keys = ['a'] }`
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof T'. 
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'. Updated the question accordingly

Comment: got it to work thanks to your suggestion, I'll edit it accordingly and mark as correct answer, thank you!

Comment: The problem you have is that TS is widening your default value. You can try to us `as const` (you will have to make `keys` readonly in `Props`), but this cannot possibly work because `a` is not a key of `Bar`.

Comment: Take note that your edit is unsafe. You are asserting something that isn't true for all `T`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest discriminated union.

```
type Foo = {
 kind: "foo";
 a: number
}

type Bar = {
  kind: "bar";
  b: number
}

type Props = Foo | Bar;

function myFunction(props: Props) {
  const value = props.kind == "foo"? props.a : props.b;
}
```

Comment: Given the keys of Foo and Bar could be a lot. I don't want to differentiate by the kind on every key, that would be a huge amount of code.